# How to disable multi-select behavior on touch-devices in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

For cytoscape.js 2.0.[0-1], on touch-devices, by default, as you click on nodes/edges, every one of them gets "selected" -- causing multiple-selections as user taps on different elements within the network. Is there an option to prevent this behavior so that every tap selects the target element and unselects the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but we will add one:

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/290